# Haskell join getHomedirectory string

Tags: string, haskell, filepath

I have a file with strings which represent directories. Some of those strings have a tilde (~) in it.
I want to join the homedirectory (~) of a user to the rest of the string. 
What I have so far:

```
import Data.List (isPrefixOf)
import System.Directory (doesDirectoryExist, getHomeDirectory)
import System.FilePath (joinPath)

getFullPath s
    | "~" `isPrefixOf` s = joinPath [getHomeDirectory, tail s]
    | otherwise          = s
```

But I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match type `IO FilePath' with `[Char]'Expected type: FilePath Actual type: IO FilePathIn the expression: getHomeDirectoryIn the first argument of `joinPath', namely `[getHomeDirectory, tail s]'In the expression: joinPath
```

I don't know, and I can't find, how to convert the types so they match and can be joined together.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A more idiomatic solution than @user2720372 suggests is to split non-monadic code from monadic code. IO actions are monadic functions in `IO` monad.

If you only need `getFullPath` locally it makes sense to cache home directory:

```
fullPath homePath s
    | "~" `isPrefixOf` s = joinPath [homePath, tail s]
    | otherwise          = s

main = do
    homePath <- getHomeDirectory
    let getFullPath = fullPath homePath
    print $ getFullPath "~/foo"
```

If you still need full global `getFullPath` then it can be implemented like this:

```
getFullPath p = do
    homePath <- getHomeDirectory
    return $ fullPath homePath p
```

And it's considered a good style to keep `fullPath` and `getFullPath` separated.

Also you don't need `isPrefixOf` and `tail` in the first place for such a simple case:

```
fullPath homePath ('~' : t) = joinPath [homePath, t]
fullPath _ s = s
```

If you want just a monolithic `getFullPath` then @user2720372's variant can be simplified:

```
getFullPath s = do
    homeDir <- getHomeDirectory
    return $ case s of
        ('~' : t) -> joinPath [homeDir, t]
        _ -> s
```

Note that the code above is just refactorings of your code preserving its wrong behavior: you should compare `~` with the first path component, not with the first path character. Use `splitPath` from `System.FilePath`:

```
getFullPath s = do
    homeDir <- getHomeDirectory
    return $ case splitPath s of
        ("~" : t) -> joinPath $ homeDir : t
        _ -> s
```

Also, do-notation is only for complicated cases. If you use do-notation for simple two-liners it is almost certainly reducible to an application of `fmap`/`<$>`/`>>=`/`>=>`/`liftM2` or other functions from `Control.Monad` and `Control.Applicative`.

Here is another version:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>))
import System.Directory (getHomeDirectory)
import System.FilePath (joinPath, splitPath)

getFullPath s = case splitPath s of
    "~/" : t -> joinPath . (: t) <$> getHomeDirectory 
    _ -> return s   

main = getFullPath "~/foo" >>= print
```

Here is yet another more modular, but less readable version:

```
import Control.Applicative ((<$>), (<*>))
import System.Directory (getHomeDirectory)
import System.FilePath (joinPath, splitPath)

main = getFullPath "~/foo" >>= print

withPathComponents f = joinPath . f . splitPath 

replaceHome p ("~/" : t) = p : t
replaceHome _ s = s

getFullPath path = withPathComponents . replaceHome <$> getHomeDirectory <*> return path
```

Haskell gurus are invited to rewrite it to preserve modularity but improve readability :)

Answer (score 3):

```
getHomeDirectory :: IO FilePath
```

`getHomeDirectory` is not a function but an IO action so you have to unpack it within another IO action first.

```
getFullPath :: String -> IO FilePath
getFullPath s = do
    homeDir <- getHomeDirectory
    if "~" `isPrefixOf` s
        then return (joinPath [homeDir, tail s])
        else return s
```